# Rolling back call to stored procedure in MySql

Tags: .net, mysql, stored-procedures, transactions

I have a scenario where I need to insert, call and drop a stored procedure in several databases. This is done in a powershell script. I want to be able to roll back the changes made by the stored procedure if some situations occur further down the in the script.

The problem is that I'm not able to roll back the changes made by the stored procedure. The stored procedure is almost 6 KB and does a number of updates and inserts, so I'm wondering if maybe it is too much for the transaction. When only doing the SP call in the transaction, I can roll it back.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$cmd = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand('', $mysqlConn)
$cmd.Transaction = $mysqlConn.BeginTransaction([System.Data.IsolationLevel]'ReadCommitted')

$cmd.CommandText = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($mySqlStoredProcedurePath)
[Void]$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

$cmd.CommandText = "CALL storedProcedureX($startHierarchyId)"
[Void]$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

$cmd.CommandText = "DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS storedProcedureX"
[Void]$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

$cmd.Transaction.Rollback()
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting when you try to roll back? What table type are you using?

Comment: I get no error message at all when running it in a test script. Maybe I should try to do it directly in mysql to see if it's the connector. The table is InnoDb. (Just edited my post regarding the 'only roll back the call' part, btw).

Comment: It seems whenever I include the create or drop of the SP the rollback doesn't happen. I tried inserting smaller updates in the same transaction as the SP call, which seems to work fine. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Does MySQL do automatic commits when DDL is issued, like Oracle used to?

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot. Quote from MySql.com :
Beginning with MySQL 5.0.13, ALTER PROCEDURE, CREATE PROCEDURE, and DROP PROCEDURE cause an implicit commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle used to do an implicit COMMIT every time that you issued a DDL statement, such as CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE TABLE, or DROP TABLE.  Perhaps MySQL does that as well?  I would check into it, especially since we now know that to be the solution (see timestamp of comments above).

Comment: Hey, I know it's cheap, but I have gotten no points in a few days and I am feeling low.

Comment: I'll give you one for this, if I'm allowed. I'm new so I have so many restrictions.

Comment: Not enough rep to ACCEPT the answer?  That seems strange.  I didn't think you needed more than 1.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to MJB for providing the clue to the answer:
[Implicit commits](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/implicit-commit.html)

> Beginning with MySQL 5.0.13, ALTER
>   PROCEDURE, CREATE PROCEDURE, and DROP
>   PROCEDURE cause an implicit commit.

Comment: Dang, no rep points, 'cause I answered as a comment.  Maybe I should create an answer and cross my fingers...

Comment: Hehe, you do that. You certainly deserve it. Saved me a lot of time!